# LWC render nested component within lightning-record-edit-form

Tags: lightning-recordeditform, lwc-dom, shadow-dom

I am working on building a LWC that componentizes lightning-record-edit-form, but the form cannot evaluate the lightning-input-field when the fields are nested within another component.

The basic model for this would be described below:

When I've tried this the fields do not render. This is probably due to the shadow tree. Does anyone know a way to make an example like this work?

```
<c-parent>
<lightning-record-edit-form>
    <lightning-button label="save" type="submit" </lightning-button>

    <!--These child components would house the fields which are built dynamically-->
    <c-child></c-child>
    <c-child></c-child>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
</c-parent>

<c-child>
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">            
    <template for:each={fields} for:item="field">
        <div key={field.Id}>
            <lightning-output-field field-name={field.APIName}> . 
            </lightning-output-field>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
</c-child>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just not possible; as you've (correctly) guessed, the Shadow DOM prevents these components from speaking to each other. The `lightning-input-field` and `lightning-output-field` must be children of `lightning-record-edit-form` in the same parent template.